# What is Upstream and Downstream services in a microservices based architecture?

Tags: microservices, api-gateway

I have heard of the terms "Upstream Services" and "Downstream Services" in general terms but I came across some articles on microservices architecture where they have used these terms. I wasn't able to understand what an upstream and downstream service in a microservices based architecture would be? Can somebody give me a brief explanation?

I already know that upstream services are those that do not depend on any other services and downstream services depend on the upstream services. For example, the front-end would be a downstream service to the backend as it depends on it.

I am developing the microservices in .Net Core.

Comment: There are tons of resources in the internet explaining this topic in detail. This could be good start point - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312401/which-way-are-downstream-and-upstream-services

Comment: I have already seen this source but this is mainly in general terms not specific to micro-services , can you provide me a link for micro-services ? i have tried searching on the net but i haven't found one !

Comment: If you are  building an API Gateway for micro-services, maybe looking at the documentation of Ocelot will give you some idea about how they define downstream and upstream - https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/routing.html

Comment: Add this question to the list of unsolved problems in computer science. :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### **Definition 1: The direction of action**

Upstream: receiving requests from / sending responses to

- A service *upstream* is calling me.

Downstream: making requests to / receiving responses from

- I am calling a service *downstream*.

### **Definition 2: The direction of dependency**

Upstream: making requests to / receiving responses from

- I am calling a service *upstream*.

Downstream: receiving requests from / sending responses to

- A service *downstream* is calling me.

### **So,**

There are resources on the internet which support both of these definitions. Maybe we will resolve this question one day, but for now the answer is: it's either.

Comment: I had the same understanding. Until today when I learned it's the other way around. With good arguments. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312401/which-way-are-downstream-and-upstream-services, and in https://reflectoring.io/upstream-downstream/ as pointed out below by Michael in the comment.

Comment: Hi @Bernd very interesting discussion. Maybe we should have a vote and settle it once and for all!

Comment: So helpful how you wrote out those 2 opposing sentences. I have been working with upstream and downstream services for years but have a hard time keeping it straight. This will help.

Comment: Can I define "Upstream" like core or domain and "Downstream" conectors and orchestrators?

Comment: @ohrlando sorry I do not understand your question

Comment: Thinking about Clean Architecture, could I identify upstreams like the components encountered at center?

Answer (score 23):

The downstream services are the ones that consume the upstream service. In particular, they depend on the upstream service. More generally, upstream services don't need to know or care about the existence of downstream services. Downstream services care about the existence of upstream services, even if they only optionally consume them.

http://reflectoring.io/upstream-downstream

Comment: Here's a nice article which supports what you say: https://reflectoring.io/upstream-downstream/

Answer (score 17):

I see it is a metaphor of water flow: the origin of a river is upstream, the outlet is downstream.

But in practice it is gibberish. Nowadays services exchange data through different means. A service can call another service to fetch data, it can also call the other service to push data. A service can receive data from another service by calls out first or it can receive data passively, like receiving push notification.

At work, you can use it judiciously: if someone who's more senior than your calls a service upstream service, go with it; if you are the most senior one on the team, name whatever you like.

Comment: that's an awesome analogy!

Answer (score 15):

**Upstream and Downstream in a Production Process**
[image]

**Upstream and Downstream Software Dependencies**
[image]

[Source](https://reflectoring.io/upstream-downstream/)

*A picture is worth a thousand words !!*

Answer (score 1):

It's the stream of service, so the provider is upstream and the consumer is downstream.

http://reflectoring.io/upstream-downstream